# Two questions about continuous mappings of compact metric spaces into themselves.

Tags: general-topology

Let $M$ be a compact metric space with distance function $d$ and let $T$ be the set of all continuous mappings of $M$ into itself. If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are any pair of mappings in $T$, let $t$ be
$$
t(f_1,f_2):=\sup_{x\in M}\{d(f_1(x),f_2(x))\}.
$$
Is $t$ a metric for $T$? If so, is $T$-with distance function $t$-a compact metric space?

Comment: For the first question: did you checked the axioms? Why is $t$ well-defined? What have you tried so far and where did you get stucked? For the second question you could use that: A subset of a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can prove by directly verifying the axioms for a metric:

- $t(f,g)=0$ iff $f=g$ for all $f,g\in T$. Indeed,
  $$
  t(f,f)=\sup_{x\in M}\{\underbrace{d(f(x),f(x))}_{=0\text{ since $d$ is a metric }}\}=\sup_{x\in M}\{0\}=0.
  $$
  and
  $$
  t(f,g)=0\Rightarrow\sup_{x\in M}\{d(f(x),g(x))\}=0\Rightarrow d(f(x),g(x))=0~\forall x\in M\Rightarrow f=g.
  $$
- $t(f,g)=t(g,f)$ for all $f,g\in T$. Indeed,
  $$
  t(f,g)=\sup_{x\in M}\{d(f(x),g(x))\}=\sup_{x\in M}\{d(g(x),f(x))\}=t(g,f),
  $$
  where I have used the fact that $d$ is a metric in the second equality.
- $t(f,g)\leq t(f,h)+t(h,g)$ for all $f,g,h\in M$. Indeed,
  $$
  t(f,g)=\sup_{x\in M}\{d(f(x),g(x))\}\leq\sup_{x\in M}\{d(f(x),h(x))+d(h(x),g(x))\}=\sup_{x\in M}\{d(f(x),h(x))\}+\sup_{x\in M}\{d(h(x),g(x))\}=t(f,h)+t(h,g)
  $$
  As far as the second part of the question is concerned, it is sufficient to consider $M:=[0,1]$, which gives rise to a counterexample.

Comment: You also need to check that $t$ is well-defined and $t(f,g) = 0 \rightarrow f = g$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed the answer accordingly

Comment: The counter example is $f_n=x^n$. This has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: Many thanks for the proof. I got bogged down trying to prove the "addition". axiom.  I was surprised by the counter-examples. In the case of "f(n)=x^n", what is the compact metric space M?